# Get data from the current month

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.3

I have a question. So I need to get data from the last days of months using a sql request. For example :

1. Now date is `22/08/2016`, I need to get data from `01/08/2016-22/08/2016`;
2. Now date is `04/06/2016`, I need to get data from `01/06/2016-04/06/2016`;

Sorry but I dont have an idea. Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
SELECT <table-columns> FROM <table-name>
WHERE (<date-column> BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND NOW() )
```

This `DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')` will return the first date of your current month and year.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use something like:

```
YEAR(time) = YEAR(NOW())
AND MONTH(time) = MONTH(NOW())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this:
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE yourDate.MONTH()=NOW().MONTH();

Refine the syntax from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the first day of the month for a given date then, in order to make your comparison with the database:

`select date(concat_ws('-',year(curdate()),lpad(month(curdate()),2,'00'),'01'));` gives you that (for `curdate()` here)